# Forward user rights to docker container

Tags: docker, permissions, jupyter-notebook, file-permissions

I'm trying to run a container on a system where I do not have any admin permissions.

The only permission I have are:

- use docker (docker run, docker volume, ...)
- Manage my own folder in `/usr/users/my_username/`

I'm using this image [jupyter/base-notebook](https://github.com/jupyter/docker-stacks/blob/master/base-notebook/Dockerfile).

I'd like to run my container like this `docker run -v /usr/users/my_username:/home/jovyan/work jupyter/base-notebook`.

But when I'm doing this, I get:

> Error stat-ing /home/jovyan/work: [Errno 116] Stale file handle: '/home/jovyan/work'

So, I tried running docker this way:

`docker run -v -u my_usernameID:0 /usr/users/my_username:/home/jovyan/work jupyter/base-notebook`

But now I have a permission error on the image user:

> PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/jovyan/.local'

Any idea on how to do it in a *clean way* ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
docker run --user jovyan -v /usr/users/my_username:/home/jovyan/work jupyter/base-notebook
```

Comment: Sadly, I guess this is the default value. I don't have access to the work folder inside the container as it's owned by my_username.